# Able to connect to object server, but not open a realm

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Good evening.

## 1  First off, love your work.

I'm using the newest version of realm-browser on osx el capitan. I can connect to my aws object server and see realms, but whenever I try to open one, it dies with a super helpful error message: 
[image]

Now I post this here for the mobile platform, because i'm also having issues connecting to it from my ios project which leads me to think I've got a server side issue.  Here's what the server side logs show: 
[image]

And the xcode logs show: 
[image]

I'm sure i'm likely doing something wrong, but no idea what. Here's a narrative overview of what I've done:
1. spun up ami realm-object-server-hvm-1474909717 (ami-80347097)
2. took the task demo, and slightly modified the authentication section to read:

```
func setupRealm() {
        let username = "Capt.Awesome@codefriar.com"
        let password = "Sup3rS3kr3tPassw0rd;"

        User.authenticate(with: Credential.usernamePassword(username: username,
                                                            password: password,
                                                            actions: []),
                          server: URL(string: "http://ec2-100.40.40.40.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9080")!,
                          onCompletion: { user, error in
            guard let user = user else {
                fatalError(String(describing: error))
            }

            // Open Realm
            let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
                syncConfiguration: (user, URL(string: "realm://ec2-100.40.40.40.compute-1.amazonaws.com/~/foo")!)
            )
            self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
            print("Realm Setup")

            // Notify us when Realm changes
            self.notificationToken = self.realm.addNotificationBlock { _ in
                print ("Realm Update occured")
            }
        })
    }
```

help me obi-won-realnobi you're my only hope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting with ROS lately, I have it working against a locally hosted ROS, haven't gotten to AWS hosting yet.

I noticed you don't have a port listed in the Realm URL for your configuration ...

Comment: I'm at 30k feet, but if I get back to my laptop and found out the issue was I didn't put a port on there ... I will hide in shame.

Comment: and 5 little characters ':9080' was all it took to fixit. Thanks Bitraven.